# Mysterious WPF exception: 'PresentationFramework.Eren Vista'

Tags: .net, wpf, exception

All of the sudden I am getting this mysterious FileNotFoundException exception inside my WPF project. It occurs right in InitializeComponent of my Window constructor:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'PresentationFramework.Eren Vista,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

I goggled for *PresentationFramework.Eren Vista* but I could not find any information on it. Do any of you have any idea what the hell this is?

**Update:** This appears to be a theme (like *PresentationFramework.Aero*, *PresentationFramework.Classic*, *PresentationFramework.Luna*, *PresentationFramework.Royal*), but I am not referencing this theme anywhere in my application.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue after I changed Win7 theme to a custom one:

> Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework.Win7-Shine2.0,
>   ...

I solved it by deleting the .suo file for my Visual Studio solution and reloading the solution.

It seems that .suo file stores some windows theme settings, resulting in a bug when you change a theme and try to rebuild the solution... wierd.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what the cause of this exception is, but I solved it by creating a new solution and adding all the same projects. WTF?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the real cause of this exception is a custom msstyles theme is being used (in this case it's named "Eren Vista")

Revert to Aero/Luna/Royale whatever that came default with .Net PresentationFramework
and the error should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar error with Xceed community DataGrid when upgrading to version 3.

I first had to add the `PresentationFramework.Luna` - which incidentally is a Microsoft DLL, not part of Xceed.

I then had to set it to Copy Local for it to find it.

[image]